# php PDO undefined function prepare()

Tags: php, pdo

I'm sure that's a real easy one, but I begin with php and can't get what is wrong.

```
function createUser ($nom, $prenom, $username, $pw, $email)
{
    $cnt = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=web', 'web', 'webuser');//getConnection ();
    $createUser = $cnt.prepare ('INSERT INTO user (NOM, PRENOM, USER_NAME, PW_HASH, EMAIL VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ');

    $createUser->execute (array ($nom, $prenom, $username, sha1($pw), $email));
}
```

I get :

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function prepare() in /home/pascal/public_html/dataaccess/users.php on line 8
```

Line 8 being `$createUser = $cnt.prepare (...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`->`, not `.`.

```
$cnt->prepare()
```

Comment: ha, we submitted almost at the same time! :))

Comment: Damn, have I said it was an easy one? I was looking at it since 30 minutes and I did not see it...

Comment: You're missing a closing paren: `INSERT INTO user (NOM, PRENOM, USER_NAME, PW_HASH, EMAIL` needs a `)`.

Comment: I really fell dumb now. Going to sleep. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I think it should be like this:

```
$cnt->prepare(..);
```